# a single String variable points to +1 value location with every click although overwrites all of them, I Think

Tags: swing

I am new here and a beginer in Java. here's my first query . i am writing this java program which will add 5 records to a database such that every time i click "submit" the top row in the database gets deleted and the bottommost row is shifted 1 record up and a new record is added to the last row . also i am adding the text in the database as JLabels on the a frame|window. everything is fine uptil this . and the database is also working as desired .except that when i click the the submit button second time in a row (i mean without closing the window or running the program again), watever i enter in the textbox ("write your blog") gets added in 3 records of the database in a single click . and when i click it the 3rd time , it adds 5 or more same records in the database . can you help me with my question . i would request anyone who answers to explain in details and perhaps post the corrected program for me , since i am just a beginner .the program code is as follows : (and yes i am only learning core java at the moment so i would request if you guide me with only the tool from the core java :**RUN IT YOURSELF AND CLICK ON SUBMIT BUTTON THRICE TO KNOW HOW VALUE CHANGES ON THE MAIN WINDOW**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class OutLoud {
    Connection con;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    JFrame Ba = new JFrame("Shout");
    JButton Bb = new JButton("Shout");
    JFrame Aa = new JFrame("Write Your Blog");
    JTextField Ab = new JTextField(100);
    JButton Ac = new JButton("Submit");
    JLabel Za;
    JLabel Zb;
    JLabel Zc;
    JLabel Zd;
    JLabel Ze;

    public OutLoud() {
        connect();
        BlogPage();
        Submit();
    }

    public void connect() {
        try {
            String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
            Class.forName(driver);
            String db = "jdbc:odbc:db1";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
            st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            String sql = "select * from Table1";
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    public void BlogPage() {
        Ba.setLayout(null);
        Ba.setSize(1024, 768);
        Ba.setVisible(true);
        Bb.setBounds(10, 210, 80, 25);
        Ba.add(Bb);
    }

    public void Submit() {
        try {
            rs.last();
            String s11 = rs.getString("Blog");
            Za = new JLabel(s11);
            Ba.add(Za);
            Za.setBounds(246, 170, 512, 100);
            rs.previous();
            String s12 = rs.getString("Blog");
            Zb = new JLabel(s12);
            Ba.add(Zb);
            Zb.setBounds(246, 275, 512, 100);
            rs.previous();
            String s13 = rs.getString("Blog");
            Zc = new JLabel(s13);
            Ba.add(Zc);
            Zc.setBounds(246, 380, 512, 100);
            rs.previous();
            String s14 = rs.getString("Blog");
            Zd = new JLabel(s14);
            Ba.add(Zd);
            Zd.setBounds(246, 485, 512, 100);
            rs.previous();
            String s15 = rs.getString("Blog");
            Ze = new JLabel(s15);
            Ba.add(Ze);
            Ze.setBounds(246, 590, 512, 100);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        Bb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Aa.setLayout(null);
                Aa.setSize(512, 384);
                Aa.setVisible(true);
                Ab.setBounds(21, 64, 450, 200);
                Aa.add(Ab);
                Ac.setBounds(206, 294, 80, 25);
                Aa.add(Ac);
                Ac.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        String s1 = Ab.getText();
                        try {
                            rs.first();
                            rs.deleteRow();
                            rs.updateString("Blog", s1);
                            rs.insertRow();
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                        }
                        Ba.remove(Za);
                        Ba.remove(Zb);
                        Ba.remove(Zc);
                        Ba.remove(Zd);
                        Ba.remove(Ze);
                        Aa.dispose();
                        Submit();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new OutLoud();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your post is unreadable. Indent your code. Use the "code" button to format code as code. Start your sentences with an upper-case letter, add some paragraphs.

Comment: Use meaningful variables and follow Java coding conventions (variables starts with a lowercase letter, classes with an upper-case one, etc...)

Comment: Sorry .. is the format readable now

Comment: @RajanChawla Look at the post now. This is "correctly indented" code.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental issue with "it inserts more values than it did last time" is that *new* event listeners are being [re-]attached inside other event listeners: thus every time an event occurs *more* (of the same) event listener is being called.

Fix: Attach the listeners *once* when the control is created and be done with it. (In fact, do *all* the "control created" stuff *once* and be done with it.)

There are likely other issues, but *the code <del>is</del> was unreadable* (the paragraph above the code is also very hard to decipher). Let the editor/IDE do the code-formatting and syntax highlighting. Coding is about hubris *and* laziness.

Comment: yes i know .. i am just a beginner .. could you explain it a little more in detail .. how should i edit this program so that event listener isn;t called multiple times

Comment: @RajanChawla Well step #1. *format the code so it is readable* (someone did this for you). Then #2 Go through the code and say "does it makes sense to perform XYZ" *when* an action is performed"?

Answer (score 0):

Rajan you are adding an action listener in the already present event listener. this is causing multiple executions. Use *Ac.addActionListener(......)* after you have initialized Ac. (i.e. place it in the constructor). Actually you place all formatting code (setBounds(...),setSize(...), .add(...),etc.) outside the actionListeners. Just use the setVisible(...) and dispose() inside the actionListeners.

Not only this, there are many errors in your program. Do not use the setBounds(...) method. It's a much better to add your components using a LayoutManager and using the pack() method.